# FTPClient with JSF 2.2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, ftp-client

I have an old project and I am very lost.

I am downloading a file from an FTP but it is not downloaded in its entirety, it is generated before it is fully completed.

Every time I give to download it is of a different size and very inferior to its real size

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect("xxxx");
    ftpClient.login("xxx", "xxxx");
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/");

    InputStream in = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(consentimiento.getRutaFichero());
    BufferedInputStream objLector = new BufferedInputStream(in);

    FacesContext objContexto = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) objContexto.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    String contentType = Utilidades.obtenerTipoDocumento("wav");
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setContentLength(in.available());
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + consentimiento.getNombreFichero() + "\"");

    BufferedOutputStream objGrabador = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    // Traspasar el contenido del fichero al objeto response
    for (int data; (data = objLector.read()) != -1;) {
        objGrabador.write(data);
    }

    objGrabador.flush();
    objGrabador.close();
    objLector.close();

    objContexto.responseComplete();
```

Comment: So if you use a fixed server local file (so no ftp) and download it via jsf it works?

Comment: Where are you actually writing the file?

Comment: @stevesmith: op is writing it here: `objGrabador.write(data);`

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, but it doesn't seem to be writing to a file but rather a stream.  It seems to be more of an FTP proxy or something?

Comment: I make a download, but make the download of the file, before it is complete.

Comment: You could try outputing the value of `data` to the screen, and see how it compares to the actual data you are expecting.

Comment: What @SteveSmith sort of means is try reading the file from FTP to your server and then in a second step write the content of the file from your server to the end user. If that works, you narrowed things down. If that does not work, you narrowed things down too. Debug... root cause investigation,